# Counting with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How would I count how many values of each distinct value there are in a specific table? I have a table with a column containing different values but a varying number of different values. I would like  create a table with one column just listing the value and another listing the number of each value.
Say i have a column 'Letter' with values A A A A B B C C going down
I just want to make a table with column 'Letter' and 'Number' with A B C vs 4 2 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT count(letter) occurences,
       letter
FROM table
GROUP BY letter
ORDER BY letter ASC
```

basically you're looking for the COUNT() function. Be aware that it is an aggregate function and you must use GROUP BY at the end of your SELECT statement

---

if you have your letters on two columns (say col1 and col2) you should first union them in a single one and do the count afterwards, like this:

```
SELECT count(letter) occurences,
       letter
FROM (SELECT col1 letter
      FROM table
      UNION 
      SELECT col2 letter
      FROM table)
GROUP BY letter 
ORDER BY letter;
```

the inner SELECT query appends the content of col2 to col1 and renames the resulting column to "letter". The outer select, counts the occurrences of each letter in this resulting column.

Comment: sorry i have an adddendum - say i have the table values A A A A | B B | C C but i have a another column with values say X X Y Z  | X Y | Y Z  . How would I make a table so that i produces a column with 'Letter' A B C and 'Number of distinct var per letter ' 3 2 2 (sorry about this im a beginner)

Comment: I will edit my answer above to accomodate the answer for this second question